# How do I keep two arrays parallel arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, boolean

The user needs to input the table number (Tables are numbered from 0 to 19). If the table is not available (reserved), inform the user that the selected table is not available. If the table is available, then ask for the name (name is a single word, no space) and mark the table as reserved. Now I need to keep two arrays (parallel arrays!), both are size 20, one of type boolean (true/false -- reserved/available) and the other one of type string (name on reservation if reserved, blank otherwise)

```
tableNum = []



def reserve():
  global table
  global name
  global tableNum

  avaible = False
  tablenum = int(input("Enter a number: "))
  if not tablenum in tableNum:
    name = input("Table is avaiable, please enter your name: ")
  else:
    print("Table is unavaiable")


while(True):
print("1- Reserve a Table")
print("2- Clear Reservation")
print("3- Report")
print("0- Exit")

choice = int(input("Choose a option "))

if choice == 1:
    reserve()
```

Comment: Instead of having two lists, why not have one list but put tuples `(available, name)` in them?

Comment: Or a single list of 40 elements, or a list of 20 objects referencing a name and a state.

Comment: Why do you need 2 lists? One list containing either a name or `None` will give you everything you need. The table is reserved if there is a name in the position or available if there is `None`

Comment: Also you're probably dealing with lists, not arrays. There's a difference in python.

Comment: how would I do that @GreenCloakGuy

Comment: Use a dictionary instead. It doesn't even need to be pre-filled with all tables, just add the booked ones. And use OO in your homework please

Comment: Hi @hewiepx1 and welcome to Stack Overflow. The way your question is currently written makes it unclear what exactly you're asking. Please [edit] it and try to spell out what exactly you'd like to know.

Comment: Idk how to explain it even more.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it without keeping a list of all the tables. Append reservations as a key, value pair to a dictionary. You can then check if the input matches a key in the reservation dictionary. You can then use the reverse to remove a reservation.

```
reservationDictionary ={}
def reserve():
    global reservationDictionary

    tablechoice = int(input('Tables are numbered 0-19, Choose a table number'))
    if tablechoice not in reservationDictionary.keys():
        name = input("Table is available, enter your Name: ")
        reservationDictionary[tablechoice] = name
    else:
        print("Table is unavailable")
```

Update to remove a booking:

```
def removeReservation():
    global reservationDictionary

    removetable = int(input('Choose table number to remove reservation for that table'))
    if removetable not in reservationDictionary.keys():
        print("This table doesn't have a reservation")
    else:
        del reservationDictionary[removetable]
        print("Reservations for table {} has been deleted".format(removetable))
```

Comment: how would I do the reverse?@Max Raju

Comment: The `del` keyword deletes the item following it @hewiepx1